# Enumerating and connecting to named pipes

Tags: windows, networking, remote-access

In windows Named pipes are available for IPC (interprocess communication) and are used both locally and remotely, Access to the remote named pipe contained in IPC$ share is done via SMB protocol,How do i Enumerate all Named pipes in system and how do i connect to named pipe contained in IPC$ share ?

some default Named pipes in Windows

1. COMNAP :- SNABase named pipe. Systems network Architecture (SNA) is a collection of network protocols that were originally developed for IBM mainframe computers.
2. COMNODE :-SNA Server named pipe.
3. SQL\QUERY :- Default named pipe for SQL Server.
4. SPOOLSS :- Named pipe for the Print Spooler service. etc